# git difftool HEAD:<FILE_NAME> HEAD^:<FILE_NAME> showing exists in disk but not on HEAD'

Tags: git

I recently pulled a code using git pull command and now I want to check what were the changes newly committed. When I tried using this command

```
git difftool HEAD:FILE_NAME HEAD^:FILE_NAME
```

I'm getting the following error:

> FILE_NAME exists on disk, but not in 'HEAD'.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Run `git status` - do you have any locally modified or new files? It seems like FILE_NAME was not committed.

Comment: Run it like this instead: `git difftool HEAD HEAD^ -- FILE_NAME`.